# C++ power function with variables

Tags: c++, pow

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double amount, rate, time, interest, month;
    interest = rate/(12.0*100);
    month = (amount * rate)/1.0 -(1.0 + interest), pow(time*12);
    cout << "What is the amount of the loan? $ ";
    cin >> amount;
    cout << "What is the annual percentage rate? ";
    cin >> rate;
    cout << "How many years will you take to pay back the loan?  ";
    cin >> time;
    cout <<"\n-------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Amount        Annual % Interest       Years         Monthly Payment\n\n\n";
    cout <<amount <<"                      " <<rate <<"               " <<time << "        " <<month;
    cout <<"\n\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am getting an error here and am not sure exactly how to use the pow function properly. The formula according to the problem is:

```
 Monthly payment = (loan amount)(monthly interest rate) / 1.0 - (1.0 + Monthly interest rate)^-(number of months)
```

Here is the line that I am having trouble with

month = (amount * rate)/1.0 -(1.0 + interest), pow(time*12);

Thanks for the help

Comment: What kind of "trouble are you having"?

Comment: What's the error you're asking about?

Comment: Shouldn't you calculate the monthly payment *after* you have the values for all the other variables?

Comment: "I am getting an error" ― does an ancient spell prevent you from disclosing its full text here?

Comment: in order to have (amount * rate)/1.0 -(1.0 + interest) raised to -(number of months) it would be something like month = (amount * rate)/1.0 -pow(1.0 + interest, time*12); ? The trouble I'm having is syntax with the pow statement and getting it to calculate the correct value.

I'm new to c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::pow` accepts two arguments like so

```
pow (7.0,3)
```

So your code should be more like this

```
month = (amount * rate)/1.0 - std::pow( (1.0 + interest), 12);
```

Your code has other flaws as well, like you do calculation before you set the values.

Comment: @MichaelGodfrey I gave you an example of how to use pow in my answer above. I will let you figure out the rest.

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware there are other errors. This is just a draft of the program. This was what I needed help with though, the other things I can fix on my own